# Complex Rails query using ActiveRecord on Many to Many relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following models

```
class Element
  has_many :tags, through: :tags_elements
end

class Tag
  has_many :elements, through: :tags_elements
end
```

I NEED: The elements that are related to all tags defined on a variable. 
i.e. all elements with tags: ["gt40", "car"]

I have tried the following:

```
class Element   
  scope :search_tags, lambda { |df|
    joins(tags_elements: :tag)
    .where('tags.name IN (?) ', df)
    .distinct('id')
  }
```

So I can do

```
tag_list = ["gt40","car"]
Element.search_tags(tag_list)
```

But it returns evert element that has ANY of the tags. However I need the elements that are related to ALL tags.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is optimal solution... but you can do

instead of scope

```
def self.search_tags(tag_list)
  elements_with_any_tags = self.joins(:tags).where(tags: {name: tag_list}).uniq

  elements_with_any_tags.select{|element| (tag_list - element.tags.map(&:name)).empty?}
end
```

this will return array of elements that has ALL of selected tags.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to:

```
Element.
  joins(:tags).
  where(:tags => {:name => ["gt40","car"]}).
  group(:id).
  having("count(*) = ?", ["gt40","car"].size)
```

In other words, make sure that the number of joined tags is equal to the number of tags in the array.