# Ruby on Rails query not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have several listings, and I define a number of filters. In particular, a listing `has_many :spaces, through: :designations` and `has_many :amenities, through: :offerings`.

I use the filters to restrict the listings that get shown.

The two main ones are:

```
# filter by space type
if params[:search][:space_ids].present? && params[:search][:space_ids].reject(&:blank?).size > 0
  @listings = @listings.joins(:spaces).where('space_id IN (?)', params[:search][:space_ids].reject(&:blank?)).uniq
end

# filter by amenities
if params[:search][:amenity_ids].present? && params[:search][:amenity_ids].reject(&:blank?).size > 0
  @listings = @listings.joins(:amenities).where(amenities: { id: params[:search][:amenity_ids].reject(&:blank?) }).group('listings.id').having('count(*) = ?', params[:search][:amenity_ids].reject(&:blank?).size)
end
```

The first filter says: get all of the listings that match ANY of the selected space types.

The second filter says: get all of the listings that have ALL of the selected amenities.

These filters work for the most part, but not always. In particular, suppose that listing A has space types 1 and 2 and amenity 2. If I filter for space types 1 and 2 (so `space_ids: ['1', '2', '']`) and amenity 2 (so `amenity_ids: ['2', '']`), I get: `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`.

But I should get listing A. What is wrong with the query?

Basically, I am trying to implement this: [Complex Rails query using ActiveRecord on Many to Many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812122/complex-rails-query-using-activerecord-on-many-to-many-relationship)

Or this: http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/6/12/when-associations-arent-enough-part-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `having('count(*) = ?', params[:search][:amenity_ids].reject(&:blank?).size)` to `having('count(*) >= ?', params[:search][:amenity_ids].reject(&:blank?).size)` (i.e., `=` to `>=`) fixes the issue.

But now there is another issue: [Ruby on Rails query yielding unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452977/ruby-on-rails-query-yielding-unexpected-results).